# browser-sync onchange event not fired on mirrored browsers

Tags: onchange, browser-sync, dom-events

Browser-sync has a feature called "Interaction sync" that allows you to "scroll, click, refresh and form actions are mirrored between browsers while you test.", however it doesn't seem to work for the onchange event.

While [React component `onChange` event not being triggered when synced with BrowserSync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39024857/react-component-onchange-event-not-being-triggered-when-synced-with-browsersyn) refers to it not working for React, it doesn't even work in a simple html with js.

A number of the forms we use have conditionally dependent fields, and this prevents you from completing a form of this type.  Is there a way around this?

I have included a simplified version of this form below.  To test this out:

1. take a copy of the below snippet and save it as an html file
2. navigate to the directory containing the html
3. open a command prompt, navigate to the html file, and run
   browser-sync start --server
4. browser-sync will launch a browser containing the default url (http:localhost:port), append "/test.html" to the url
5. copy the url to another browser

You'll see that while the selection of the dropdown mirrors, the event and associated javascript don't fire.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Title of the document</title>
        <style>
            .hide{
                display:none !important;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <h1>Conditional Form</h1>
            <label>dependee</label>
            <select name="radioGroup" id="radioGroup" onchange="displayDependent();">
                <option value="-1">--</option>
                <option value="radio1">radio1</option> 
                <option value="radio2">radio2</option>
            </select>
            <div id="text1Group" class="hide">
                <label>text1</label>
                <input type="text" name="text1">
            </div>
            <div id="text2Group" class="hide">
                <label>text2</label>
                <input type="text" name="text2">
            </div>
            <div id="text3Group">
                <label>text3</label>
                <input type="text" name="text3">
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        function displayDependent() {
            var dropDownSelect = document.getElementById('radioGroup').value;
            // hide both
            if (dropDownSelect == "-1") {
                $("#text1Group").addClass("hide");
                $("#text2Group").addClass("hide");
            }
            // show 1 hide 2
            if (dropDownSelect == "radio1") {
                $("#text1Group").removeClass("hide");
                $("#text2Group").addClass("hide");
            }
            // show 2 hide 1
            if (dropDownSelect == "radio2") {
                $("#text2Group").removeClass("hide");
                $("#text1Group").addClass("hide");
            }
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't look like it is available at this time.

Stumbled upon this github issue, shortly after:
https://github.com/BrowserSync/browser-sync/issues/22